# Meta description of my blog post changes

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-index, meta-tags, meta-description

I have some problems in **Meta description** tags in my **Blogger blog**. When I update my pages in search engine with the help of the **Fetch as Google** feature in GWT, all my blog's results comes with a correct **meta description** like

> Today I am back with a reason that "WHY IS ORIGINAL MEMORY IN HARD-DISK IS LESS THAN PRINTED" on a box. If we buy any hard-disk or a pen drive...

But after approx 5-6 days, it changes to my blog's default **meta description**. This is also happening after changing the default **meta description** of my blog.

I want only one answer that **why** its happening?

After deleting my blog and creating a new blog with the same name this problem was solved.

Why this problem was solved? - I am asking this question because to solve problems in the future.

Comment: Google will change your meta description snippet and page title in their search results as they see fit.

Answer (score 2):

The snippet in search results can change depending on what query you enter and Google doesnt always use your defined meta description.

> Google will *sometimes* use the meta description of a page in search
>   results snippets, if we think it gives users a more accurate
>   description than would be possible purely from the on-page content.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en